# To connect MySQL GUI Tools 5.0 with android

Tags: android, android-edittext, mysql-gui-tools

How can I able to connect the MySQL GUI Tools 5.0 with android program, and then I need to know how to store a data in MySQL GUI Tools 5.0 using an editText in android.
If anyone knows the link about my query please convey me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: you just want to connect mysql remote database with your app??

Comment: No no.. Not like that my frnd. I just need to save a data in MySQL using editText. For example-MySQL act as a administrator, so Admin can able to edit in MySQL.